# how to python pssh with smash clp

Tags: python, pssh

I'm trying to automate getting the status of 500 servers.
I can ssh into the server bmc console which brings up a smash clp terminal using a valid username and password and run the command: `chassis --get power status` and this returns on screen: `The host status is on`

I have done pssh to the server but in the case of the server being off I would like to pssh through the BMC console and run the same command to check if the server is available. When I use the same method for pssh on the console that I do on the server nothing happens. There is no return no error it sits there executing the script until I force it to stop.

How can I pssh to the smash clp?

My simple test script:

```
from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient

hosts = ['server-con']
username='uname'
password='password'
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, username, password)
output = client.run_command('chassis --get power status')
for host, host_output in output.items():
    for line in host_output.stdout:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know BMC console or chassis, but from my understanding, you are trying to wrap in python ssh command to run remotely and having a problem with that.

My suggestion is to simply use subprocess and run it

```
output = subprocess.run("ssh foo chassis --get power status", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```